# CSS mini-fling timing

Tags: css

How could I tweak this if I was using images that I didn't want to have transitions in and out for. For example, I have 6 testimonial images I want to use but I don't want the fade in/out - I just want them to swap.

This is what I have now:

```
    /* Mini Slideshow Effect */
.fling-minislide {width:350px; height:300px; overflow:hidden; position:relative; }
.fling-minislide img{ position:absolute; animation:fling-minislide 180s infinite; opacity:0;}
@keyframes fling-minislide {25%{opacity:1;} 40%{opacity:0;}}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(6){animation-delay:0s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(5){animation-delay:30s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(4){animation-delay:60s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(3){animation-delay:90s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(2){animation-delay:120s;}
.fling-minislide img:nth-child(1){animation-delay:150s;}
```

Comment: `...animation:fling-minislide 0s;`

Comment: @zer00ne, that's what I'd have thought as well but when I change that in the CSS file, none of them load.

Comment: Try a very small time duration that's seems instant to human perception like: `0.1s`